# CQ5 is not getting installed as publisher in windows service

Tags: service, aem

I am trying to install the AEM CQ as windows service in publish mode. But it is getting installed as an author.
I have changed the variable to publish in instsrv.bat 
D:\AdobeAEM\crx-quickstart\opt\helpers\instsrv.bat

```
    :: runmode(s)
set cq_runmode="publish"

:: HTTP port
set cq_port=4503
```

Still, it is opening in author mode.
I have not configured author in this server
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

if you are working con CQ5.5 It's ok, but in AEM(5.6) It's impossible to install it as publish mode if you installed it as author before.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described it sounds like you added JVM parameters to the jvm_options variable without separating the values with the # character.  If you don't separate them with '#' or ';' then the runmode will not get included in the `--JvmOptions=` parameter passed to prunsrv.  See the section code below from instsrv.bat which shows this.

```
:: default JVM options
:: separate multiple entries by ";" or "#"
:: if you need these chars put them inside single quotes
set jvm_options=-XX:MaxPermSize=256M

::* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
::* do not configure below this point
::* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set main_class=org.apache.sling.launchpad.app.Main
set start_param=start#-c#.#-i#launchpad
if defined cq_runmode   (set jvm_options=%jvm_options%#-Dsling.run.modes=%cq_runmode%)
```

Part of script that calls prunsrv:

```
:run_install
chdir /D %~dp0
prunsrv //IS//%service_name% --Description="%service_description%" --DisplayName="%service_name%" --Startup="%service_startmode%" --StartPath=%context% --Classpath=%CQ_JARFILE% --JvmMx=%jvm_mx% --JvmOptions=%jvm_options% --StdOutput=%context%\logs\startup.log --StdError=%context%\logs\startup.log --LogPath=%context%\logs --PidFile=..\conf\cq.pid --StartMode jvm --StartClass=%main_class% --StartParams=%start_param% --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=%main_class% --StopParams=%stop_param% --Jvm=%jvm_path%
if defined start (net start %service_name%)
goto exit
```